# Uninstall Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, python, uninstall

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 which comes with Python 2.7. I have installed Python 3.3, so now I have both versions. For example, if I type python in the terminal I get version 2.7 and if I type python3.3 I get that version.

I don't see why I would need 2 versions (?) so how do I uninstall Python 2.7? And if I do so, will the "python" command then point to Python 3.3?

Comment: There are several **important** programs that depend on Python 2.7, so it's not recommended to remove it. You can add `alias py="python3"` to your `~/.bashrc` if you only need a shorthand.

Comment: [PEP 394](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) recommends that `python` starts some version of Python 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you won't need Python-2.7 in a month?

Maybe you'll start some programming in Python using OpenCV or some other packages, for which bindings to Python3 do not exist yet in the repository.

Seriously, I'd just leave Python-2.7 there - it doesn't harm.

---

Edit:

I'd rather additionally install ipython and ipython notebook for both versions. You will not regret it.